# GCP Transcoder API takes a 5+ seconds to start the job

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-transcoder

We are using the GCP Transcoder API via a Google Cloud Function. The Transcoder API provides the proper result, but it often takes 5 or more seconds before the Transcoder API begins processing the job. We know this by monitoring the getJob response and seeing that it remains at "PENDING" for the length of time mentioned above.

Does anyone have experience with the GCP Transcoder API that might be able to tell us if this is expected and/or experienced behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

The Transcoder API (v1) is now GA. We made updates to job prioritization compared to (v1beta1). Please test using v1 as v1beta1 has been deprecated.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30124106)

Comment: This does not require clarification. The requester is using a deprecated product. They need to test using the current/supported version of the API.